# Genymotion Emulator Screen flickers while using X.Org X server(AMD/ATI display driver wrapper)

Tags: drivers, 14.04, ati, android

I have been facing this weird situation in Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit) while using Genymotion emulator. I have always used X.Org X server opensource driver for daily use. The driver is working fine, except the genymotion emulator screen flickers(when trying to access the android notification panel).

I contacted the genymotion support. They mentioned that this situation may be due to the graphics card(Mine is ATI Radeon HD 54xx).I switched to AMD proprietary drivers, the problem with android notification panel seems to be gone. The problem with this is the laptop boots with low resolution boot(till the login appears).

I have currently switched back to X.Org driver as this problem is not that huge. But I would love to have it solved.

Comment: Currently a show stopper to me. Hope they fix this, as fglrx is hugely in conflict with wine (wine fault, I think)